# Найти data-value на странице

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="abs">
<div class="panel-tag">
<i data-value="675"></i>
</div>
</div>

<button onclick="click()"></button>

<script>
function click(){
// узнать есть ли  data-value="675"

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идет именно об атрибутах DOM-элементов:

```js
var numb='i675';
//if ($("[data-value='675']").length > 0) {
if (document.getElementById("abs").querySelector("[data-value='" + numb + "']") != null) {
  console.log("I has it!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abs">
  <div class="panel-tag">
    <i data-value="i675"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: метка же не jquery :-/

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ой-ой-ой, простите!

Comment: А если  var numb='i675';  if ($("[data-value="+numb+"]").length > 0) {

Comment: @Нетглупыхвопросов - что значит "var numb='i675';"?

Comment: Как быть если будет переменная?

Comment: @Нетглупыхвопросов так что ли?

Comment: var  pay_prt = 'i675'; if (document.querySelector("[data-value='" + pay_prt + "']") != null) {alert( "dfdfdf");} Так должно сработать?

Comment: @Нетглупыхвопросов посмотрите на текущий вариант кода в ответе и нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код"

Comment: А если например именно в , что в div id="abs" мой вариант верен или нет?  var div = document.getElementById("abs"); if (div.querySelector("[data-value='" + numb + "']") != null) {...

Comment: @Нетглупыхвопросов да, так тоже можно, если надо ограничить область поиска частью дерева DOM

Comment: Спасибо, большое!

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="abs">
<div class="panel-tag">
<i data-value="675"></i>
</div>
</div>

<button onclick="click('675')"></button>

<script>
function click(numb){
// 1 Пример
var element = document.querySelector('[data-value="' + numb + '"]');
if (element) {
   console.log('есть  data-value="' + numb + '"');
}
// 2 Пример 
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-value]');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   if (elements[i].dataset.value === numb.toString())
      console.log('есть data-value="' + numb + '"');
      break;
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Может я чтото не так понял ?

Comment: так понял, молодец. Подозреваю, что автор вопроса сейчас скажет, что в переменной у него склеены название тага и значение `data-value`.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**
Синтаксис прост - любой атрибут, чье имя начинается с data-, является data-* атрибутом. Предположим у вас имеется статья и вы хотите сохранить дополнительную информацию без визуального представления. Используйте для этого data-атрибуты:

**JavaScript**
Читать data attributes в JavaScript также легко. Вы можете использовать getAttribute() для чтения. Но стандарты предоставляют более простой способ: DOMStringMap вы можете читать свойства через dataset:

```js
var article = document.querySelector('#electriccars'),
              data = article.dataset;
 
console.log(data.columns); // -> "3"
console.log(data.indexNumber); // -> "12314"
console.log(data.parent); // -> "cars"
```

```html
<article
  id="electriccars"
  data-columns="3"
  data-index-number="12314"
  data-parent="cars">
</article>
```