# Как выбрать data атрибуты по значению

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице несколько блоков с data-атрибутом

```
<div data-ajax="value1"></div>
...
<div data-ajax="value2"></div>
...
<div data-ajax="valueN"></div>
```

Есть вот такой код

```
var LoadOnScreen = function () {
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    var $block = jQuery('[data-ajax="value1"]');
    var $data = $block.data('product');
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() >= $block.offset().top) {
        if(!$block.attr('loaded')) {
            $block.attr('loaded', true);

            RunSpinner(); // show Spinner

            setTimeout(function () {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "/url/to/" + $block + "/" + $data,
                    type: "get",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (template) {
                        StopSpinner(); // hide the spinner
                        $block.html(template);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        $block.html("<p>Произошла ошибка при получении данных</p>");
                    }
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

};

Когда блок появился на экране, посылается аякс запрос. Если просто оставить `data-ajax` без значения, то при появлении первого блока с этим атрибутом, он посылает запрос для всех блоков.

Вопрос в том, как можно динамически подставить значение в дата атрибут? Примерно так `jQuery('[data-ajax="' + value + '"]');`, а потом как нибудь проверить значение атрибута, и послать аякс запрос?

Comment: _Когда блок появился на экране, посылается аякс запрос_ - а откуда он взялся?

Comment: В функции этот аякс запрос идет, после `RunSpinner();`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Найти data-value на странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676159/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-data-value-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам всего-навсего требовалось правильно выбирать блоки, для которых посылать ajax-запросы. Это можно обеспечить с помощью [`.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/):

```js
function showDisplayingBlocks() {
  // получаем список требуемых для загрузки блоков
  let blocks = $.grep($('div[data-ajax]'), function(el) {
    // проверяем на то, загружен ли блок
    let loaded = $(el).data('loaded');
    if (loaded)
      return false;

    // проверяем на отображение блока во вьюпорте
    let elementOffset = $(el).offset().top;
    let elementHeight = $(el).height();
    let windowOffset = $(window).scrollTop();
    let windowHeight = $(window).height();
    if (windowOffset > elementOffset + elementHeight)
      return false;
    if (windowOffset + windowHeight < elementOffset)
      return false;
    return true;
  });

  // отправляем ajax-запросы для всех требуемых блоков 
  $(blocks).each(function() {
    let el = $(this);
    el.html('Loading...');
    el.data('loaded', true);
    let ajaxData = el.data('ajax');

    // имитация ajax-запроса
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.html('<span>3</span>');
      setTimeout(function() {
        el.html('<span>2</span>');
        setTimeout(function() {
          el.html('<span>1</span>');
          setTimeout(function() {
            el.html('Loaded ' + ajaxData);
          }, 1000);
        }, 1000);
      }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

$(document).ready(showDisplayingBlocks);
$(document).scroll(showDisplayingBlocks);
```

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  line-height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  font-size: 60px;
}

div:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-ajax="value1"></div>
<div data-ajax="value2"></div>
<div data-ajax="value3"></div>
<div data-ajax="value4"></div>
<div data-ajax="value5"></div>
<div data-ajax="value6"></div>
```

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо!)